Electric field to an infinitely long hollow half cylinder
What would be the electric field induced because of a uniformly charged infinitely long half hollow cylinder at a unit charge B that lies along the central axis of the half cylinder


You will have to tell us where the charges are, is $B$ a point charge or is there charge elsewhere? (Or both?)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRrlRQxL8xA

I don't see the correct answer there... At least not for a conductive half-cylinder, I think the video assumes uniform charge density, but that's much too easy! A metal half-cylinder would have a vertical field in point B with value:
$$
{\bf E} = \frac{\sqrt2 \ Q\ {\bf \hat{z}}}{2\pi \varepsilon_0 r }
$$
if it has charge $Q$ per unit length. You can see this by conformal mapping: https://i.sstatic.net/FEQHEnVo.png but since someone closed the question I can't elaborate further on it...

I don't see why this isn't solvable by integration like any other problem. Please clarify if you are experiencing any specific conceptual issue.

@Vincent The charge distribution is not known  in the half-cylinder if you assume it is a conductor and it is at constant potential, which I did. Charge will accumulate at the edges in an a priori unknown way. In that case it gives a very interesting example of applying conformal mapping! And a challenge for you: how would you solve that case by integration? What integration would you do?

@JosBergervoet Did you read the question? It clearly states "uniformly-charged", which means that the charge distribution is uniform and constant in time. To calculate the field is straightforward integration.

I see, my fault! At least to some extent... In the original version the uniform charge was not mentioned. But in a later edit it was added: https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/811636/revisions
